# Why arguments which passed to .sh file are missing after sudo su?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, arguments, parameter

I need to run `.sh` file on my server from my local machine.
I could do it using below command.

```
ssh -p my_port_no -i path_to_key user@ip_address "bash -s" < testOnServer.sh
```

Now I need to pass some arguments with above command. I did it as below and it was success.

```
ssh -p my_port_no -i path_to_key user@ip_address "bash -s" < testOnServer.sh testArg1
```

My `testOnServer.sh` file is as below.

```
testArg1=$1

echo testArg1   # testArg1 can be seen here.
sudo su
echo testArg1 # testArg1 is missing here.
```

Value of `testArg1` is missing after `sudo su` command.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `sudo su` starts a complete different shell.

Comment: how can I get `testArg1` from that shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The use of sudo su changes the shell to a new user, namely root. As such the variables are not available in the new shell.

To share variables you would have to publish them to the environment, for root to access. So the value testArg1 is not "missing" after sudo su command... it is not being printed as you changed shell.

Rather edit the sudoers file to allow your user to run the command you require, if you must, directly.

See previous posts like [Block all default commands while a bash script are running?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546064/block-all-default-commands-while-a-bash-script-are-running/546073#546073), regarding the use of "source" etc. for controlling variable access. And read up a bit about Bash variable scope, eg. using the [Bash User Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjVjIv1_77lAhWzmFwKHShWCqQQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tldp.org%2FLDP%2FBash-Beginners-Guide%2Fhtml%2F&usg=AOvVaw16xIwrHkKJ7aB-fjf0nF0I).

Comment: As well, `sudo` is often configured to discard arbitrary environment variables i.e. even if plain `su` inherits an environment variable, `sudo su` might not (although `sudo -E su` might - if policy allows it)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer